# Is it possible to backup Network Manager profiles?

Tags: backup

Is it possible to backup NetworkManager created profiles and restore them after OS reinstalation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those profiles will be located in

> /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/

You can just backup these files (with root privilege) and restore them later.

Comment: This does not include personal (non-system) connections

Comment: And you need to remove the MAC addresses in the files.